# Track events in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a Visual Studio WPF C# Solution that has hundreds of classes and projects that I need to maintain. I want to track down a problem in the software but have NO CLUE where the class is in the solution. Is there a way to track events in Visual Studio to help me track this class down?

For example say I start the program and I go to the section of the program that is having the issue. I then click on a button 100 times. Is there an output that will tell me where that event is being fired?

Comment: "You're going to have to be more specific than "a problem"; are you getting a compiler error? A runtime exception? Unexpected results? In what; your application or in Visual Studio? Question as stated is unanswerable.

Comment: The problem is irrelevant. There is no error. Question has been answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For WPF application, you can use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to find the class name of the control. After starting it, you can drag a target marker to needed control, and it will be shown in control tree, with all its properties.

It can also show you all the events as they occur in WPF controls.

Comment: what is the difference of Snoop and Inspect/UISpy?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for just giving me an appropriate, constructive, non-snarky, non-obscure answer.

Comment: @David, I've personally used Snoop a couple of times, and it did its job. It is not the only tool, but i think it would be a good starting point for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) to log your event with different levels such as warning, info and error.
See also [this post](http://sadi02.wordpress.com/2008/06/29/log4net-tutorial-in-c-net-how-can-i-show-log-in-a-file/) for a quick tutorial.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a "quick" tutorial for Log4Net?  Any logging facility will do, including the `Trace` class that is already available in the Framework.

Comment: The answer is yes and no. If you prefer to be very precise, you are correct, and for some beginners, an example is worth thousands of words. What I mean by "quick" is to make the OP to have a quick start. Does this make some sense from your standpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Run the program.

[image]

With the program running go back to visual studio and click pause (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>).

[image]

Then click step into (or press <kbd>F11</kbd>).

[image]

Your app will get focus back.

Trigger the event.

The focus will go to visual studio where the event handler code will be highlighted.

[image]

Comment: I think OP does not know where to put the breakpoint, because he has 1000 wpf controls and does not know which one are currently shown on screen.

Comment: When I hit the step into button I don't get control back of the app. I think its because there is to much going on in the background for this method to work.

Comment: @AMR: Wait a few seconds, or just alt-tab back to it then. It brought it back into focus for me.

Comment: @alex: You don't need to put a breakpoint anywhere.